# find and remove substring in string using regexp in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

In Javascript or ruby, i need to find a substring using regex and remove it from my main string which could contain several substrings.

My main string is

```
 My <style type="">first</style> name <style>is</style> xyz <style>abc</style>.
```

I need to remove all the text within the style tag including the style tag.

I have tried the following expression and several other variations

```
(<style .*>[^<>]*?<\/style>)
(<style .*>[^<>]*<\/style>)
```

The resulting string i want is

```
My name xyz.
```

but i could not find the right way. What I get instead is

```
<style type="">first</style> name <style>is</style> xyz <style>abc</style>
```

What is the correct regex for this?

Note: cannot use any JS libraries like jquery and others.

Comment: change `[^<>]` to `[^<]` and this should fix your problems assuming no nested tags. You'll also need to change `<style .*>` to `<style\b[^<].*>`, actually. Not every `<style>` in your example has a _type_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do it:

```
str = 'My <style type="">first</style> name <style>is</style> xyz <style>abc</style>.';
str = str.replace("<style[^>]*?>.*?</style>","");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'My <style type="">first</style> name <style>is</style> xyz <style>abc</style>.'
.replace(/<style[^>]*>[^<]*<\/style>/g,'');
"My  name  xyz ."
```

but essentially you're trying to parse xml with regex, which is not really possible.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use DOM parsing to remove the undesired nodes.

```
var el = document.createElement('div');
el.innerHTML = 'My <style type="">first</style> name <style>is</style> xyz <style>abc</style>.';
var styles = el.getElementsByTagName('style');
for(var i = styles.length - 1; i >= 0; i--){
    console.log(styles);
    el.removeChild(styles[i]);
}
el.innerHTML; // My name xyz
```

Answer (score 0):

you can try this

`[<\/][a-z]+[a-z][ ][a-z]+[=]["]["][>]|[<][\/][a-z]+[>]|[<][a-z]+[>]`

and [click here for output](http://regexpal.com/?flags=g&regex=%5B%3C%5C%2F%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5Ba-z%5D%5B%20%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5B%3D%5D%5B%22%5D%5B%22%5D%5B%3E%5D|%5B%3C%5D%5B%5C%2F%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5B%3E%5D|%5B%3C%5D%5Ba-z%5D%2B%5B%3E%5D&input=%20My%20%3Cstyle%20type%3D%22%22%3Efirst%3C%2Fstyle%3E%20name%20%3Cstyle%3Eis%3C%2Fstyle%3E%20xyz%20%3Cstyle%3Eabc%3C%2Fstyle%3E.)